# If formula show diffrent result

Tags: excel, if-statement

I need formula to show me different result

```
 "if" O18>O16
=IF($O$18>$O$16;O19);IF($O$16>=A27;$O$17+A27;"")
```

But it is not working.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: _but not working_ - What result are you getting? What were you expecting?

Comment: #value I want to show me if IF($O$16>=A27;$O$17+A27;"") O17 or If O18>O16 to show me O19.

Comment: `#value` error means you are trying to do an operation with a wrong value (e.g. sum a text value). Make sure all the values in the cells you are referencing in your formula are numbers and are formated as numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want IF O18>O16 THEN O19 ElSE IF O16 > A27 then O17+A27 ELSE ""  ?

```
 =IF(O18>O16,O19,IF(O16>A27,O17+A27,""))
```